# SSL SNI support on iOS by default also in older versions?

Tags: ios, ssl, sni

I have an app that connects to Apache server with SNI enabled to support several Virtualhosts

In iOS 7.1.1 and older iOs versions the connection fails with this visible error in Apache (when in debug mode):

```
Apache-Error: [file "ssl_engine_kernel.c"] [line 512] [level 7] Changed client verification type will force renegotiation
Apache-Error: [file "/builddir/build/BUILD/httpd-2.2.15/modules/ssl/ssl_engine_kernel.c"] [line 542] [level 6] Non-default virtual host with SSLVerify set to 'require' and VirtualHost-specific CA certificate list is only available to clients with TLS server name indication (SNI) support
```

it works instead when SNI is disabled in Apache, the correct virtualhost is the default or iOS version >= 8 is used.

The question is: Is in iOS SNI ON by default? It looks like yes on iOS >= 8.0 and no in <8.

If it is not on by default in old iOS versions (is what looks like), anyone knows how to force SNI sending?

Thanks in advance